# CSS - Div to always match container width, even once the container is scrolled horizontally

Tags: css

Given this simplified layout:

```
<div id="container" style="width:calc( 100% - 200px); height:600px; background-color:blue; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;">

<div style="width:1000px; height:200px; background-color: green;"></div>

<div style="width:auto; height:100px; background-color: red;"></div>

</div>
```

On a large screen, the red takes up the entire width of the blue container and no scroll bar is needed.

On a small screen, the blue container becomes scrollable, and the red still appears to take up the whole width of the blue container. But once scrolled, we can see the red actually breaks off before the green does.

Is it possible for the red to **always** take up the full width of the blue container, no matter what screen size, and even once scrolled?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/spjnzwto/1/

Edit: The fixed width values provided only act as examples, and are not necessarily static.

Comment: You have two `width` settings in the red DIV. The second one (auto) will always overwrite the first one, so 500px will never be used as a width setting.

Comment: My bad - corrected for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript could do the trick :) look at the example below. The red div gets its width from the blue divs scrollwidth.

```js
document.getElementById('red').style.width = document.getElementById('blue').scrollWidth + 'px';
```

```html
<div style="width:calc( 100% - 200px); height:600px; background-color:blue; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;" id="blue">

<div style="width:1000px; height:200px; background-color: green;" id="green"></div>

<div style="height:100px; background-color: red;" id="red"></div>

</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/spjnzwto/6/

Using this it will work on window-resize, too. `<body onresize="document.getElementById('red').style.width = document.getElementById('blue').scrollWidth + 'px'">`

or you could use an eventlistener using javascript...

Comment: I try not to resort to JS for display but this works simply and effectively, thank you!

Comment: unfortunately, there is no way to get the scrollwidth of a parent-div using css. you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

You write: "Is it possible for the red to always take up the full width of the blue container, no matter what screen size, and even once scrolled?"

Actually the answer is quite simple and requires no Javascript: Yes, give it `width: 100%;` and  `min-width:1000px;`

https://jsfiddle.net/bvqpuz48/2/

Comment: this is only a static solution, my solution is working dynamically with every overflow-width of the blue div.

Comment: @J.Sadi I don't know what you mean by "static solution"? You can try any width you like, it works.

Comment: for example: the green div isn't an static element with a width of 1000px, it could be an "one-line text" or one of an image from a list of images with different widths..... this is what i mean with "static/dynamic solution"

Comment: @J.Sadi In the given situation (i.e. in the question) the green DIV has  a fixed width, with no overflow possibility. That's what I wrote my answer for. It's a very particular layout anyway, and I can't imagine why it would be like that, but I wrote my answer exactly for the situation in that question, anything else would only be speculation.

Comment: i am pretty sure, that the given fiddle is only an simple example using elements to simulate something, and not the final layout, thats the reason why i've speculated and provided an dynamically solution ^^

Comment: J.Sadi is correct in that the fixed width was only for the example, which is why I've taken that solution.But Johannes is spot on, and I should have mentioned this to be more specific in my question (I'll update). The CSS-only solution is excellent and the better option where a fixed width is used, the other for something more dynamic. Both useful answers.